# What is the NR_Syscalls value?

Tags: linux-kernel, c, system-calls, syscalls

I am trying to understand code for a C program that among other things, increments the `NR_syscalls` value of the Linux kernel.  Does the NR_syscalls value store the number of system calls in the system calls table?

Comment: @Kusalananda this C code is dealing with the Linux system call table.

Comment: Still unclear: Are you talking about a C ***program*** or a C function ***in the kernel*** ?  If it's a program, how is it manipulating kernel data?  In any case, can you tell overall what the code is doing?   (Can you tell us?)

Comment: @G-Man Although unixes have traditionally a very strong separation between the user and kernel space, there are still some shared data structures, mainly to make their interactions more feasible. include/linux is nearly the same in the kernel and the glibc source. The list of the system calls is one of them - simply your app has to see the same id of sys_open, as the kernel api. _NR_syscalls is the upper index of the array of the linux system calls.

Comment: @peterh Very little of what you’re saying makes any sense to me, least of all the suggestion that a user mode program can *modify* kernel data without using a system call specifically designed for that purpose.

Comment: @G-Man Of course no user program can modify kernel data (except very extraordinary things, like going to ring0 with `sys_iopl`, although it happens mainly for direct hw control and not for modifying kernel data structures), also _NR_syscalls is a static value (as I can remember, it isn't even a const, but a `#define` somewhere below `/usr/include/linux`). For example, `strace` uses it. Another example for shared data structures are, for example, the headers describing filesystems or network protocols. These are used mainly by kernel, but sometimes also by user space (for example, `tcpdump`

Comment: @G-Man or `e2fsck` has to know, how the ethernet packets or the ext4 directory entries look in their physical form). If you create a socket, but not an `AF_INET` socket, rather an `AF_PACKET` socket, you will be able to send/receive incoming ethernet packets directly. To create/analyze these packets, typically glibc headers are used, which were once kernel-space headers in the kernel source (in the libc5 era, even for the compilation of the libc5 you had to have a recent kernel source because of that).

Comment: @G-Man But that is right that these all are declarations, and never executable code. Any code which is capable to run in both kernel and userspace, could be possible in Linux, I don't know even a single example as it had been written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, exactly this is what it does.